# Dynamodb Table Design

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I need a table which should have following attributes: userId, commentId, commentTopic, commentCountry. I want to avoid using Secondary Global indexes. What should be best design which will allow me the followings operations:

```
1) Get all comments belonging to a userId.
2) Get a comment with commentID = "commentID"
3) Get comments of all users  where topic = "commentTopic" and country = "commentCountry"
```

I am thinking to have:

```
1) userId#commentId as partitionKey which will uniformly distribute the load and allow me to perform operation 1 and 2 from above list.
2) commentCountry#commentTopic as RangeKey which will allow me to perform operation 3 efficiently.
```

Is there any drawback of this approach. Will this table design be efficient? What are disadvantages of concatenating multiple keys together?

Comment: When you write "userId#commentId" do mean that it is a single attribute of a string type that contains two cocatenated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one idea that you can use. You can define one table **Comments** with the following attributes:

- **UserId** (String) - partition key
- **CommentId** (String) - sort key

Define the following GSI:

- **CommentId** (String) - GSI partition key

And the following GSI:

- **CommentTopicAndCommentCountry** (String, GSI partition key) - combined field that has two values combined together, something like "123_Germany"
- **CommentId** (String, GSI sort key) the very same field as before

Now your queries:

> Get all comments belonging to a userId

this is pretty straightforward, just use partition key/sort key and specify only a partition key.

> Get a comment with commentID = "commentID"

Use first GSI and provide a  comment id.

> Get comments of all users where topic = "commentTopic" and country = "commentCountry"

Use second GSI and provide a value for "comment id and country" as a single partition key value.

Now the limitation is that you can only have up to 10GB of data for a single partition key, so if this is likely that you can end up having more than 10GB of messages written by a user or more than 10GB of messages in a single topic, you may want to use multiple tables instead of a single table.

You can have **Comments_2017**, **Comments_2016**, etc. to store comments for different years. You can go more granular than that if you want to.

An additional benefit of this is that you can set different RCU/WCU values for different tables. I would imagine that newer comments are read more often, so you can set high RCU/WCI for the latest table, but old comments are not written at all and maybe read less often. In this case you can set less RCUs there.

Answer (score 0):

```
PK = USER#userid 
SK = COMMENT#commentId(GSIPK)
GSISK = commentTopic#country
```

Get all comments from a user

```
PK = USER#userid AND SK START_WITH COMMENT#
```

Get a comment by comment id can be against GSI

```
GSIPK = COMMENT#commentId
```

Get comments of all users  where topic = "commentTopic" and country = "commentCountry"

```
GSIPK START_WITH COMMENT# AND GSISK = commentTopic#country
```